# Elasticsearch empty an object

Tags: elasticsearch

New to ES. I am trying to create users index which will allow visitors to search users. To make sure that I can display profile pictures on search results, I also have an image object. My data looks like the following.

```
"_source": {
     "username": "pewpewlasers",
     "name": "Pew Pew",
     "image": {
          "filename": "filename.jpg",
          "uid": 14
     }
}
```

What I do is every time these data change, I use the update API (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html) to update the fields. This works great except when the user deletes the profile picture.

Generally I would send a request like:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test/users/1/_update' -d '{
    "doc" : {
        "image" : {
                    "filename": "newfilename.jpg",
                    "uid": 15
                }
    }
}'
```

works great. However whenever the user removes profile picture, I try to send the following request:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test/users/1/_update' -d '{
    "doc" : {
        "image" : {}
    }
}'
```

This does not replace the old image data with empty object, thus giving me incorrect information in search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test/users/1/_update' -d '{
  "doc": {
    "image": null
  }
}'
```

From [this section](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_dealing_with_null_values.html#_dealing_with_null_values) of the documentation, `null`, `[]` and `[null]` are all equivalent and in a query like the following they would return all the documents that don't have a value for `image`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "missing": {
          "field": "image"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```